# Ads not showing in android game

Tags: java, android

I downloaded an android game, and I wanted to test it, but the thing is, It won't show the adMobs even if the code contain 'em :

in the main.java here's the adMob code (I am using eclipse) :

```
// AdMob

AdView adMob_smart;
    InterstitialAd adMob_interstitial;
    final boolean show_admob_smart = true; // show AdMob Smart banner
    final boolean show_admob_interstitial = true; // show AdMob Interstitial


// AdMob Interstitial
        if (num_games == 5) {
            num_games = 0;
            add_admob_interstitial();
        }

// add_admob_smart
    void add_admob_smart() {
        if (show_admob_smart
                && ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
            adMob_smart = new AdView(this);
            adMob_smart.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMob_smart));
            adMob_smart.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.admob)).addView(adMob_smart);
            com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            // builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("4d0555dfcad9b000");
            adMob_smart.loadAd(builder.build());
        }
    }

    // add_admob_interstitial
    void add_admob_interstitial() {
        if (show_admob_interstitial
                && ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
            adMob_interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
            adMob_interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMob_interstitial));
            com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            // builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("4d0555dfcad9b000");
            adMob_interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();

                    if (findViewById(R.id.mess).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        adMob_interstitial.show();
                }
            });
            adMob_interstitial.loadAd(builder.build());
        }
    }
```

and this is the code in string.xml :

```
<!-- AdMob Smart Banner ID -->
    <string name="adMob_smart">ca-app-pub-3310939034790481/3513231854</string>
    <!-- AdMob Interstitial ID -->
    <string name="adMob_interstitial">ca-app-pub-3310939034790481/3206249053</string>
```

I am new to android, but I am learning so far how to develop android games.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, did you `import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds` ?

or did you already in the build.gradle add

```
maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
```